# Android resource IDs - how are they created?

Tags: android-layout

I see that Android creates an unique id for each resources we create in the layout and stores in the R.java; These IDs seem to be hexadecimal numbers; not the GUID; How are they unique? How are they created? This question is just out of curiosity; Please do not explain me about the Resources again but the logic behind the unique id generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE, i.e. Eclipse, has an [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) for Android development. It automatically re-generates the R.java file and assigns unique IDs to new resources.